# error setting java String[] to postgres prepared statement

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I'm  trying to insert an Array of Strings into Postgres.  I get an invalid type error from Postgres.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    String[] skus = { "0514", "0414", "0314", "0214", "0114", "1213", "1113", "1013", "0913", "0813", "0713", "0613" };
    String sqlString = "Insert into dbo.Inventory_Metrics skus values(?)";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(getPostgresConnUrl());
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sqlString);

    //THIS NEXT LINE THROWS AN ERROR

    ps.setObject(1, skus, java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR, skus.length);
    int status = ps.executeUpdate();
    ps.close();

    System.out.print(status);
}
public static String getPostgresConnUrl() {
    String database = "mycode";
    String userName = "xxxxxxxx";
    String password = "xxxxxxxx";
    return "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.50:5432/" + database + "?user=" + userName + "&password=" + password;

}
```

Comment: But you have a single question mark, and an array of values. You might try a string of comma-separated values instead.

Comment: The JDBC API doesn't work this way. Please describe what you want to achieve. On top of that: PostgreSQL doesn't support the `NVARCHAR` type afaik

Comment: ps.setObject(1, skus, java.sql.Types.VARCHAR, skus.length);  //Fixes error, post it as the answer.

Comment: Near-identical repost at http://stackoverflow.com/q/26005620/398670 . (+1, thanks for including your code and the error message. In future, your PostgreSQL and PgJDBC version should also be included in all questions).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use the [JDBC array API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html), per the documentation.

You can't just `setObject` an array in JDBC. It'd be nice if that's how it works, but it isn't. You're expected to handle arrays specially.

```
Array jdbcSkus = con.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", skus);
pstmt.setArray(2, jdbcSkus);
```

Comment: @NathanHughes Re your deleted answer - Most DBMSs support native arrays, and [it's almost never right to store comma-separated data](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/55871/7788) if you can avoid it.

Comment: agreed, it was just unclear what the OP wanted. i assumed nvarchar was right and went with that, then deleted when I saw Mark's comment. couldn't agree more about avoiding comma-separated data (*almost never* might not be strong enough wording). not sure an array is much better though.