# Does PostgreSQL have the equivalent of an Oracle ArrayBind?

Tags: postgresql

Oracle has the ability to do bulk inserts by passing arrays as bind variables.  The database then does a separate row insert for each member of the array:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html

Thus if I have an array:

string[] arr = { 1, 2, 3}

And I pass this as a bind to my SQL:

insert into my_table(my_col) values (:arr)

I end up with 3 rows in the table.

Is there a way to do this in PostgreSQL w/o modifying the SQL?  (i.e. I don't want to use the copy command, an explicit multirow insert, etc)

Comment: The question is not about inserting an array, but about inserting several rows in a single statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot do that in PostgreSQL.

You'll either have to use a multi-row `INSERT` or a `COPY` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Nearest that you can use is :

```
insert into my_table(my_col) SELECT unnest(:arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

PgJDBC supports `COPY`, and that's about your best option. I know it's not what you want, and it's frustrating that you have to use a different row representation, but it's about the best you'll get.

That said, you will find that if you prepare a statement then addBatch and executeBatch, you'll get pretty solid performance. Sufficiently so that it's not usually worth caring about using `COPY`. See [`Statement.executeBatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeBatch()). You can create "array bind" on top of that with a trivial function that's a few lines long. It's not as good as server-side array binding, but it'll do pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which language you're targeting, but in Java, for example, this is possible using `Connection.createArrayOf()`.

Related question / answer:
[error setting java String[] to postgres prepared statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25999014/error-setting-java-string-to-postgres-prepared-statement)

Comment: This link appears to be describing passing an array as a parameter- not the equivalent of the Oracle ArrayBind.  (i.e. you would end up with a single row  with an array value in a column, not the multiple row expansion that the ArrayBind functionality provides)